# Powershell to take screenshot from the SSRS report and attache to mail

Tags: powershell, reporting-services, powershell-3.0

How to take screeshot of the SSRS report using powershell and send a mail the same screenshot  using Send-Mailmessage.

Is this possible using powershell?

help much appreciated.

thanks in advance

Comment: Export your report as PDF, for example ( http://myrshost/ReportServer?/myreport&rs:Format=PDF ) then mail it.

Comment: Screenshots of reports are useless to the consumer. You should be producing PDF, Excel or Word output.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rolling your own solution based on, say, [Graphics.CopyFromScreen()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.copyfromscreen%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), using SSRS built-in features ought to be much more easy to maintain.

Take a look at [file share delivery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159264.aspx) and [subscriptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159762.aspx) of SSRS reports.

Answer (score 0):

While it may be *possible*, it's the wrong approach.

[Set up SSRS subscriptions to schedule the execution & delivery of your reports.](https://www.google.com/#q=ssrs+schedule+report) As part of the subscription, configure it to produce [PDF](https://www.google.com/#q=ssrs+pdf+output) or [Excel](https://www.google.com/#q=ssrs+excel+output) output (or Word or RTF, if that's more appropriate).